# What is the right way to set back button arrow tint in ios 13

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios13, uinavigationbarappearance

In ios 13, Apple introduced the new UINavigationBarAppearance proxy object to set the navigation bar appearance. I've been able to set almost everything I needed except one small thing. The back button's arrow is always rendered with blue tint color and I have no idea how to set it to the color I want. I am using the old `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:]` way, but I think there has to be some way to do it with the UINavigationBarAppearance objects API. Anybody has any idea how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The new way of setting the back button color of the appearance (proxy) would be:

```swift
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

// Apply the configuration option of your choice
appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
            
// Create button appearance, with the custom color
let buttonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .plain)
buttonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

// Apply button appearance
appearance.buttonAppearance = buttonAppearance

// Apply tint to the back arrow "chevron"
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white

// Apply proxy
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance

// Perhaps you'd want to set these as well depending on your design:
UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

Answer (score 8):

I have a custom navigation controller setup in my app, which modifies `navigationBar`s `titleTextAttributes`, `tintColor` and others depending on different scenarios.

Running the app on iOS 13 the `backBarButtonItem` arrow had default blue tint color.
The view debugger showed that only the `UIBarButtonItem`s `UIImageView` had this blue tint.

What I ended up doing was setting the `navigationBar.tintColor` twice for it to change the color...

```swift
public class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    public var preferredNavigationBarTintColor: UIColor?

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }


    public func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

        // if you want to change color, you have to set it twice
        viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .none
        viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = preferredNavigationBarTintColor ?? .white

        // following line removes the text from back button
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    }
```

The weirdest part when looking for solution was the inconsistent result, which makes me think its related to view life cycle and/or appearance animations or Xcode cache :)

Comment: Can't believe all the hack-fixes that we need to do to support iOS 13 :/ Thanks for the fix btw!

Comment: Strange, I don't have to set it to `.none` or `nil`, I just give it a color after setting the appearance and it just works