# Cancel button text color on Mail Compose View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using iOS 14 device and whenever I open Mail View Composer, the 'Cancel' button on top left corner always shows up in white. I was able to set the color of send button, but not able to change the color for 'Cancel' button.

```
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(toRecipientEmailIds)
    mailComposerVC.setSubject(subject)
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)

    if let topVC = UIApplication.shared.topMostViewController() {
        mailComposerVC.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x057AFF)
        //mailComposerVC.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        //mailComposerVC.navigationBar.isOpaque = false
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.white
        topVC.present(mailComposerVC, animated: true)
    }
```

How do I change text color for 'Cancel' button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below as it probably is what is causing your cancel button to be white

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.white
```

You only need this

```
// set any color you want
mailComposerVC.navigationBar.tintColor = .green
```

[image: MFMailComposerView cancel button navigation bar button tint swift iOS]

Comment: What iOS version are you using? Sorry I mentioned iOS 14 in the description, my device is set to iOS 15 but while googling somewhere I read the issue is on iOS14+. I removed the line you pointed, but I am still seeing cancel button text in white.

Comment: @tech_human I am actually using an iOS 14.4 device so this is probably an iOS 15 issue then. Have a look at some of these then for iOS 15 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733936/change-color-of-back-button-in-navigation-bar or https://stackoverflow.com/a/58377778/1619193 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111478/ios-15-navigation-bar-transparent

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links! I will give look at it and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your AppDelegate.swift has set the value for all the NavigateBar

UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .normal)

Just remove above line, you will be able to set your mail cancel button color.

Please refer to this post:
[Cancel and send button missing on MFMailComposeViewController iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189722/)